# keras fit_generator for multiple batches and multiple inputs

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am currently generating a `data_generate(batch_size)`  which takes in 
`batch_size` as argument.

My network is multi  input network, which has 33 inputs of shape `(45,8,3)`

if the batch size = 1 , then i can easily yield my input data as a `[33 inputs]`, but when the batch size becomes > 1, is when I am not sure how i should format my input data.

doing this `[[33 inputs], [33 inputs], [33 inputs] , [33 inputs], .. ,[33 inputs] ]` does not seem to work, as keras expect the first entry in the list to be a numpy.ndarray,  which in this case is a list of numpy ndarrays.

I could give it a list of numpy arrays of shape (33,45,8,3), so something like  `[(33,45,8,3),(33,45,8,3),(33,45,8,3),....,(33,45,8,3)]`

but this causes this error when i tested with 2:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 33 arrays but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([[[[ 3.,  4.,  4.],
```

So what is the desired input format?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the desired format for your input is :

a list of 33 numpy arrays of shape `(batch_size, 45, 8, 3)`, the first dimension will be the batch.